# ASP.NET, jQuery, dirty forms, and window.onbeforeunload

Tags: asp.net, jquery, onbeforeunload

In my ASP.NET web app, I'm trying to create a universal way of warning users before navigating away from a form when they've made changes, using jQuery. Pretty standard stuff, but after a lot of searching I have yet to find a technique that works.

Here's what I have at this point:

```
    addToPostBack = function(func) {
        var old__doPostBack = __doPostBack;
        if (typeof __doPostBack != 'function') {
            __doPostBack = func;
        } else {
            __doPostBack = function() {
                old__doPostBack();
                func();
            }
        }
    }

    var isDirty = false;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        addToPostBack(function() {
            alert("Postback detected.")
            clearDirty();
        });
        $(':input').bind("change select keydown", setDirty);
        window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
            var msg = "You have unsaved changes. "
            if (isDirty == true) {
                var e = e || window.event;
                if (e) { e.returnValue = msg; }
                return msg;
            }
        };
    });

    setDirty = function() {isDirty = true;}

    clearDirty = function() {isDirty = false;}
```

This works as far as warning the user from navigating away. The problem is that I get the warning on every same-page postback. There are a number of things on my forms that might trigger a postback:

1. There are Save, Cancel, and Delete linkbuttons on the page
2. There might be other linkbuttons on the page that execute server-side functionality while staying on the same page
3. There might be other controls with autopostback=true that also have server-side functions attached to them, but which don't result in the user leaving the page.

None of these things should provoke a warning, because the user isn't leaving the page. My code tries to hijack addToPostBack ([more details on that in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230573/how-to-capture-submit-event-using-jquery-in-an-asp-net-application/1234845)) to clear the isDirty bit before posting back, but the problem is that in IE `onbeforeunload` fires before __doPostBack, apparently because IE fires onbeforeunload immediately when a link is clicked ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317423/asp-net-linkbutton-raising-onbeforeunload-event-twice)).

Of course, I could wire up each of these controls to clear the isDirty bit, but I'd prefer a solution that operates on the form level and that doesn't require that I touch every single control that might trigger a postback.

Does anyone have an approach that works in ASP.NET and that doesn't involve wiring up every control that might cause a postback?

Comment: You could just cheat and check the SO source code to see what they do.

Comment: SO uses beforeunload, but it's MVC == no postbacks == doesn't have Herb's particular problem.

Answer (score 8):

I came across this post while Googling for a solution for doing the same thing in MVC. This solution, adapted from Herb's above, seems to work well.  Since there's nothing MVC-specific about this, it should work just as well for PHP, Classic ASP, or any other kind of application that uses HTML and JQuery.

```
var isDirty = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':input').bind("change select keydown", setDirty);
    $('form').submit(clearDirty);

    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        var msg = "You have unsaved changes. "
        if (isDirty == true) {
            var e = e || window.event;
            if (e) { e.returnValue = msg; }
            return msg;
        }
    };
});

setDirty = function () { isDirty = true; }
clearDirty = function () { isDirty = false; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always create an inherited page class that has a custom `OnLoad` / `OnUnload` method that adds in immediate execution JavaScript.

Then you don't have to handle it at a control specific level but rather the form / page level.

Comment: Not clear on what you're suggesting. What would this this method/methods do?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting, but... why don't you do everything with jQuery?

```
var  defaultSubmitControl = false;
var  dirty = false;
$(document).ready(function( ) {
    $('form').submit(function( ) { dirty = false });
    $(window).unload(function( ) {
        if ( dirty && confirm('Save?') ) {
            __doPastBack(defaultSubmitControl || $('form :submit[id]').get(0).id, '');
        }
    });
});
···
dirty = true;
···
```

Now, if that still causes the same issue (`unload` triggering before `submit`), you could try a different *event tree*, so instead of calling `__doPostBack` directly you do...

```
setTimeout(function( ) {
    __doPastBack(defaultSubmitControl || $('form :submit[id]').get(0).id, '');
}, 1);  // I think using 0 (zero) works too
```

I haven't tried this and it's from the top of my head, but I think it could be a way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Got this to work by basically tracking the mouse position.  Keep in mind you can still get positive values to your Y value (hence my < 50 line of code), but as long as your submit buttons are more than 100 pixels down you should be fine.

Here is the Javascript I added to track mouse changes and capture the onbeforeunload event:

```
    <script language="JavaScript1.2">
    <!--

    // Detect if the browser is IE or not.
    // If it is not IE, we assume that the browser is NS.
    var IE = document.all?true:false

    // If NS -- that is, !IE -- then set up for mouse capture
    if (!IE) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)

    // Set-up to use getMouseXY function onMouseMove
    document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;

    // Temporary variables to hold mouse x-y pos.s
    var tempX = 0
    var tempY = 0

    // Main function to retrieve mouse x-y pos.s

    function getMouseXY(e) {
      if (IE) { // grab the x-y pos.s if browser is IE
        tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
        tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
      } else {  // grab the x-y pos.s if browser is NS
        tempX = e.pageX
        tempY = e.pageY
      }  
      // catch possible negative values in NS4
      if (tempX < 0){tempX = 0}
      if (tempY < 0){tempY = 0}  
      // show the position values in the form named Show
      // in the text fields named MouseX and MouseY
      document.Show.MouseX.value = tempX
      document.Show.MouseY.value = tempY
      return true
    }

    //-->
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onbeforeunload = HandleOnClose;

        function HandleOnClose(e) {

            var posY = 0;
            var elem = document.getElementsByName('MouseY');
            if (elem[0]) {
                posY = elem[0].value;
            }

            if (posY < 50) {    // Your form "submit" buttons will hopefully be more than 100 pixels down due to movement
                return "You have not selected an option, are you sure you want to close?";
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Then just add the following form onto your page:

```
    <form name="Show">
        <input type="hidden" name="MouseX" value="0" size="4">
        <input type="hidden" name="MouseY" value="0" style="display:block" size="0">
    </form>
```

And that's it!  It could use a little cleanup (remove the MouseX, etc), but this worked in my existing ASP.net 3.5 application and thought I would post to help anyone out.  Works in IE 7 and Firefox 3.6, haven't tried Chrome yet.

Answer (score 0):

i am looking after this too but what i have find so far is, a solution that uses all the **html controls** instead of asp.net web controls, have you think of that?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("form").dirty_form();
      $("#btnCancel").dirty_stopper();
    });             
  </script>
```