# Detect if any input box on a panel changed

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I detect if any control on a panel has value changed? Is there any event gets fired on a panel if control value changes?

I am having some issues with query printElement() plug in. For that I have to detect changes on panel without a postback.

Thanks,

Comment: You should be able to use the code from this question:

[Detecting Unsaved Changes using JavaScript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155739/detecting-unsaved-changes-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Are they just input controls?  If so you can use jquery to track when they change.

Comment: This Panel is my custom control and used thruout my app which will have not only input controls, I am having issue: If there is a text box on a panel, user changes value in a text box and without postback when users tries to use Jquery printElement() it's not printing updated value