# Multiple forms & Navigating away from unsaved changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am using this: [Alert for unsaved changes in form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844256/alert-for-unsaved-changes-in-form) to alert for unsaved changes.

My issue is that I have multiple forms on my page:
 - SearchForm
 - RecordForm

I only want the alert to trigger for the RecordForm and not the SearchForm.

I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to do is set an `id` to RecordForm container, and then change the selector to trigger the event:

```
// In this case 'record-form' is the id
$("#record-form :input").change(function(){
    unsaved = true;
});
```