# Check if link is clicked in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

EDIT: My question is different from the 'supposedly duplicate' because mine is checking how to not trigger off an event when a link is clicked, the other question is about how to detect changes in a form.

I am using a function ([taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155739/detecting-unsaved-changes)) to detect any changes made to a form before leaving the page, this works fine however it also triggers off when I click the save button as I am using the `onbeforeunload` event to fire of the function and I want to prevent this from happening when I click my save button.

Here is my event:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (formIsDirty(document.forms[0])) {
        // For IE and Firefox
        if (e) {
            e.returnValue = "You have unsaved changes.";
            alert("You have unsaved changes.");
        }
        // For Safari
        return "You have unsaved changes.";
        alert("You have unsaved changes.");
    }
};
```

How can I prevent this event from firing when this particular save link is clicked?

Link:

```
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbtnSave" href='/save'>
<img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Image5" class="imgvalign" src="../../images/icons/save.gif"> Save
 </a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting Unsaved Changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155739/detecting-unsaved-changes)

Comment: The answer to your question is actually in your linked question. You need to track that state of the form and use a click handler on the save button to update that state.

Comment: No it is not, Please show me the answer then?

Answer (score 0):

```
event.target //DOM object.

event.target.id  //id of source element.

sourceElement = $(event.target.id); // will get you jQuery object
```

you can check the element is Submit button or not.If yes then no need to display the message

Comment: he can check the id of element no need of Jquery

Comment: `event.target.id` doesn't do anything in my case, here is what I have used: `if (e.target.id === "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbtnSave") {
       //save button was clicked
       return false;
        }`

Comment: @user3574492 why you need to fire an event. You can use the function to detect changes in the save click function na. Correct me if am wrong

Comment: @AnoopLL I am using the `window.onbeforeunload` event to detect if the user tries to navigate away from the current page. This is why I am using an event to try to get the target id, the target id is the save button